# Smallest (in size) object to hold unique number?

Tags: java, memory, uuid

I have a situation where I have a lot computers and need to have unique IDs.

They would send their uniqueIds with API request. The object looks like

```
class ID {
 long timestamp;
 int id;
}
```

The smallest size possible for this object is `24 bytes (8 byte long, 4 byte int, 8 byte object reference and 4 byte padding)`. I need to keep millions of these objects in memory, which is why memory is concern. I need `timestamp` for ordering purposes.

I initially thought of that every node when it starts will have `UUID` (as unique String.  Since `UUID` takes `128 bits` it can not fit in `Int` range

What are my options?

Comment: Have you considered having each client generate, for each request, a 16-byte GUID via `UUID.randomUUID()`? And maybe holding those 16 bytes as 2 longs in an existing object?

Comment: Why not you only use timestamp as an id, when do you instantiate an new object, it's probably very unlikely to have duplicate timestamps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even with your object taking 24 bytes total.  Even if you have 10's of millions that is only 240 MB.   A big number to be sure, but small compared to the size of most modern PC's.

So I assume you have some situation that limits your RAM.

So let's say you have millions of these objects.  Presumably they will be stored on a hard drive.  Otherwise when the power fails you will lose millions of references.  If you don't need to iterate the list often you could store them on the HDD to relieve RAM.

If that is not possible, let me suggest replacing the linked list of objects with an array of TimeStamps.  Just the time stamps.  YOu then index into the array with the ID number.  Of course this presumes that the ID numbers start at 0 and go into the millions.  If they are randomly distributed in the domain of 32 bit integers, then this won't work.

Now you only need 8 bytes per entry.  If you need to find what ID goes with a particular time stamp, then you need to search the entire array looking for that time stamp.   If you need search the for the timestamp of a particular ID, then you just index the array.  `return timstamps[index];`

If you are adding and deleting items, then you may want to keep variables that keep track of the total number of active elements.

Comment: With parallel arrays of primitives, how would you support deletion of the ID for a completed request? Are you presuming that all requests complete quickly, to allow use of a circular queue?

Comment: I think there was a cut/paste error in my text. I will try to fix it up. I was not suggesting parallel arrays.    What I meant to say is that you have one array of timestamps. Then you index into that array with the 4 byte ID number.   If the ID numbers are sequential (starting from zero) then there is a one to one correspondance between ID numbers and the index into the array.   If you need to delete an ID, then you could store '0' in the time variable to indicate a dead element.

Comment: That seems to presume that there is at most one concurrent request from each computer.

Comment: Yes, I was making that assumption.   I apologize if you stated otherwise.  the array idea won't work if that is not true.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you need **only** millions of these object. So, in the `int`, you still have **thousands** of those milions.

So, I would go just with int, composed of `MACHINE ID` + `NUMBER`.

If you have 1000 machines, you will have about 2 millions of numbers, but I suppose you have smaller amount, so for example even with 100 machines you still have 20 millions of possible numbers...

Additionaly, such numbers you can just generate by incrementation, without randomization - because each machine will have it's own scope.

```
0 - 20 000 000: Machine 1 scope
21 000 000 - 40 000 000: Machine 2 scope
....
1 000 000 000 - 1 020 000 000: Machine ~100 scope
```

**Also, do not include things like padding or reference** - even if your API is object-oriented, you can still made an "optimized storage", that will hold all/grop of your values just in an array (maybe even grouoped by timestamp, so you could have like array of 10000 integers, with 1000 corresponding timestamps etc.

Comment: `int` is for machine id, timestamp will be long, uniqueness if based on `id:timestamp`

Comment: Do you really need timestamp?

Comment: Usually, timestamps are used for scheduling. It's only a guess, but I think that is what OP is using it for.

Comment: Yes, `timestamp` is required, because at server, I need to order the request from various nodes based on `timestamp`

Comment: Maybe you can reduce your timestamp absolute value to the less significant 32-bits? So you end up with 2x int per request.